# MDBootstrap Datatable Not Auto-styling Correctly

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

With my Laravel project I'm using MDBootstrap to style a datatable. However, when running the following script at the bottom of my page to create the datatable, the included [Search function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHfYp.png) and the [pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rDWk.png) do not get styled and do not get classes added to them. The ["Show Entries"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJS3h.png) button at the top left also does not get styled by MDB. Looking at the first [example](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/datatables/) on Bootstrap webpage, the search function gets styled automatically and the pagination get styled with buttons with the same scripts and styling that I have included. Do you see anything that I could be missing?

```
        // Material Design example
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
            });
            $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
        });
    </script>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="float-left">
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-light-blue">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/datatables2.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        // Material Design example
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
            });
            $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css');

// Bootstrap
//@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// MDBootstrap
@import '~mdbootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '~mdbootstrap/css/mdb.min.css';
@import '~mdbootstrap/css/addons/datatables2.min.css';

//Awesome Font
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    <title>Datatable Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br>
    @include('inc.messages')
    @yield('content')
</div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    @yield('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    // require('bootstrap');
    require('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/jquery.min.js');
    require('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/popper.min.js');
    require('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    require('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js');
    require('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/addons/datatables2.min.js');

} catch (e) {}


/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     forceTLS: true
// });
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/jquery.min.js', 'public/js')
    .js('node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/popper.min.js', 'public/js')
    .js('node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'public/js')
    .js('node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/addons/datatables2.min.js', 'public/js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was more scripting that was missing for styling. After including the following script after my scripts and before the DataTable function at the bottom of **index.blade.app** created the styling I was looking for.

```
    <!-- Datatable Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
```